# When playing ARK; PulseAudio cannot change playback device

Tags: kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, steam, soundcard

I've got a weird issue that requires someone with more Pulse Audio experience than I have.

Whenever I launch "Ark: Survival Evolved" through Steam, on KUbuntu 16.04, I have no sound. I've checked Pulse and it shows that the audio is being piped to the system sound device; I attempt to change it to my USB external sound card (which works for everything else), and it refuses to change. The menu closes, and it's still defaulting to "Built-In Analog Stereo", which isn't hooked up to anything.

I did not have this issue on KUbuntu 14.04; and this is a fresh install on a different hard drive. No configuration files were copied over, just music, pictures, videos, and documents. I've used Pulse for a long time (musician), and with a lot of different equipment; I've never had this issue with anything before and I've done some weird stuff.

The current "solution" is either to attach my speakers to my default audio output--which is not easy due to space limitations--or to play it on another OS, which is just obnoxious.

Is there a way to set it up to pipe to a specific output before starting the program? Given that this is early access, I'm guessing that it just isn't "getting" Pulse Audio when it attempts to pipe; but I could be wrong.

Thanks for any help you can give me. This is my chill-out game. It isn't worth a reboot.

UPDATE:
I discovered that most of this can be resolved by copying default.pa from /etc/pulse to ~/.config/pulse ; special thanks to Nebuzaradan at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293399/how-to-set-hdmi-sound-output-as-default-on-ubuntu-16-04 . This forces every program, including the fidgety ones like the above, to default to the settings established in it. Probable bug?

ADDITIONAL UPDATE:
My method seems to work, but occasionally requires me to kill and restart pulseaudio; which is a move from highly-inconvenient to a-lot-less-inconvenient-but-not-quite-perfect. I'm still not sure what's going on with the default file; but will update this for others who have the same question as I figure it all out.

Comment: Not sure if relevant to ARK, but similar issue has been discussed on Steam with Revenge of the Titans and FEZ, and the solution there works for me on Tropico 5. Seems Tropico 5, FEZ, and RofT all use OpenALSoft for sound, and it by default sets a flag DONT_MOVE to the audio stream. You can change the behaviour via config file, see: http://steamcommunity.com/app/93200/discussions/0/864959809826195633/

Comment: You can also configure it system-widely by editing `/etc/openal/alsoft.conf`.

Comment: My current solution is to run pulseaudio ---k after startup. This causes pulse to read the appropriate settings file. It isn't a real solution as the behavior still exists, but it's functional.